# Large image issue in opencv

Tags: image, opencv

Hi I was working on one project related to opencv..algo work good in image of sized around (600 * 700) size of image but not working properly on (2000 * 3264) size of image.
I tried resizing it but its giving problem to smaller images.How to deal with the image size.
Generally I am resizing using mspaint and then passing it to my algo.

Small Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeMmU.png
Large image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HH63E.png

Also when i read large image it gets rotated automatically.

Comment: I don't understand your problem

Comment: I will write algo for u :
1> Take a image 
2>Find Outer rectangle of the image (you can see smaller image )
3>warpPerspective on orignal image with corner pts.
Now my question :
1> Will it work on smaller and larger images,larger images are not giving proper results so I am doing resizing to (600*700).

2> When i load larger images it is rotating the image by 90 degrees.

Comment: Now, I am lost even more. What is exactly the problem? You said that "I tried resizing it but its giving problem". But what kind of problem you have when resizing? OpenCV has a resize() function, you don't need to resize using MS Paint. Also, there must be some line in your code that does rotate an image and if not, your picture Viewer shows it in a bad rotation. We need more info or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is **resizing**, try to use the built-in OpenCv function `resize()` for `Mat` or `cvresize()` for `Iplimage`.

For more information: [OpenCV image-resizing doc](https://sites.google.com/site/pdopencv/images/image-resizing)